# django-filter SQLite3 DateRanges with Startdate and Enddate

Tags: python, django, sqlite, date-range, django-filter

At the moment I'm working on a Django webapplication which is supposed to search through a database with historical persons ('Person'). These persons had offices ('Amt') in different locations ('Ort'). Here are the models:

```
from django.db import models
class Person(models.Model):
    Sortiername = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Ansichtsname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Erste_Erwaehnung = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    GND = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Wikidata = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Bemerkung = models.CharField(max_length=2500)

class Amt(models.Model):
    Person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    AmtDeutsch = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    AmtLatein = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Klerus = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Ort = models.ForeignKey(Ort, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    AmtStart = models.DateField()
    AmtEnde = models.DateField()

class Ort(models.Model):
    OrtDeutsch = models.CharField(max_length=50) 
    OrtLatein = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    GND = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    GPS = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I built this filter using django-filters, which allows me to filter the persons by all the necessary parameters:

```
import django_filters
from .models import Person, Amt, Ort

class PersonFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    Ansichtsname = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains', label='Name')    

#the following two paragraphs are filtering all categories of offices ('Amt') to feed a dropdown menu in the search template  
    get_aemter_dt = Amt.objects.all()
    aemter_dt_lst_1 = []
    for amt in get_aemter_dt:
        if amt.AmtDeutsch != "nicht vorhanden":
                aemter_dt_lst_1.append((amt.AmtDeutsch, amt.AmtDeutsch))
    aemter_dt_lst_2 = sorted(list(set(aemter_dt_lst_1)))
    aemter_dt_tpl = tuple(aemter_dt_lst_2)
    amt__AmtDeutsch = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(lookup_expr='icontains', label="Amt (Deutsch)", choices = aemter_dt_tpl)

    get_aemter_lat = Amt.objects.all()
    aemter_lat_lst_1 = []
    for amt in get_aemter_lat:
        if amt.AmtLatein != "nicht vorhanden":
                aemter_lat_lst_1.append((amt.AmtLatein, amt.AmtLatein))
    aemter_lat_lst_2 = sorted(list(set(aemter_lat_lst_1)))
    aemter_lat_tpl = tuple(aemter_lat_lst_2)
    amt__AmtLatein = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(lookup_expr='icontains', label='Amt (Latein)', choices = aemter_lat_tpl)

#Basic django-filters stuff

    Erste_Erwaehnung = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains', label='Erste Erwähnung')
    GND = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains', label='GND')
    Wikidata = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains', label='Wikidata')

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['Ansichtsname','amt__AmtDeutsch', 'amt__AmtLatein',]
```

And this is the template:

```
{% block content %}
  <form method="get">
    {{ person_filter.form.as_table }}
    <button type="submit">Suche</button>
  </form>
  <ul>
  {% for person in person_filter.qs %}
    <li><a href="/personen/personen/{{ person.id }}/">{{ person.Ansichtsname }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

I know, it's probably a bit messy, but it does what I want it to do. Except for one thing: As you can see, each office has a start date ("AmtStart") and an end date ("AmtEnde"). I now need to integrate a search filter/form, that allows me to query by a date range. However, the date range is supposed to take both the start AND end date into account (I know how to do it with a single one). I will give an example: Let's say there's five persons in the DB with an office each:

- A (AmtStart = 0875-01-01; AmtEnde = 0880-01-01)
- B (AmtStart = 0840-01-01; AmtEnde = 0890-01-01)
- C (AmtStart = 0810-01-01; AmtEnde = 0876-01-01)
- D (AmtStart = 0877-01-01; AmtEnde = 0895-01-01)
- E (AmtStart = 0810-01-01; AmtEnde = 0820-01-01)

When I search for the date range 0874-01-01 to 0881-01-01 I want to match every person of the above, except for person E.

I have tried several things, but they didn't work at all. The solution in my opinion would be, to build a query that grabs each person, where either AmtStart <= search start date and AmtEnde >= search end date, or AmtStart/AmtEnde is in between the two dates. How can I combine this into a single query, and how can I integrate it in my filter/template? 
Thank you, if you need any more info, let me know!

Edit: Added imports and deleted unnecessary stuff, you should be able to run the code now.

Comment: What is 'Ort'? What do I need to import to make it run? (in     Ort = models.ForeignKey(Ort, on_delete=models.CASCADE))

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't explain that. 'Ort' just means 'location' and is a ForeignKey which points to a table with locations (basically, where the office was held, so for example archbishop of Milano). I'm editing in the imports right now. Thank you for your help!